# DNS - public address for local zone

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind, dns-zone

I am facing an issue I don't quite know how to solve it.

So I have two internal dns servers, let's say dns1 and dns2.
They serve a zone let's say z1.mydomain.com - and internally everything is working out fine.

Also, mydomain.com has a public DNS server that answers for the mydomain.com zone, and all I did was to add z1.mydomain.com to this zone to resolve from the outside.

My problem is when I try to ping z1.mydomain.com from the inside, I can't resolve host. I'm sure I'm missing something, but can someone please give me a help?

Comment: So you have a zone `z1.mydomain.com` with hosts under it - `s1.z1.mydomain.com` and now you have added a record `z1.mydomain.com` to your public DNS server. You are now trying to access the PUBLIC `z1.mydomain.com` record and it's not resolving ... Am I understanding your issue correctly?

Comment: I think you are! My current location/cluster is z1.mydomain.com and I have several hosts, s1.z1.mydomain.com and dns1.z1.mydomain.com for example. But when I use a reference internally to z1.mydomain.com not resolving!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add an A record to the apex of your domain. In bind that would look like:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
$TTL 300
...
(NS records, TTL, MX, SOA, etc here)
    A     123.123.123.123

z1  IN  A  10.10.10.10
```

Comment: Hi, I did that on for the zone mydomain.com, which is public. On my local domain, if I add z1 IN A it will consider this as z1.z1.mydomain.com. Meanwhile I fixed it by adding z1.mydomain.com. IN A publicIP and it's working, but I'm still checking this topic trying to understand if this is the correct fix or if there is another solution!!